# Connect iPad to Linux computer using ethernet over USB C (forming a "mini-network")

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, subnets, ios

I teach a class which requires me to switch between projecting my ipad (handwritten notes) and my computer desktop (code, simulations, etc.).

To do this, I installed uxplay which allows me to host an airplay server on my computer, and I have no issues mirroring my ipad on my home network. However, the network at my job is not compatible with airplay, so I need a different solution. I noticed that if I turn off wifi on the laptop and iphone, and then tether my computer to the iphone using USB, my laptop gets an IP address and I can mirror the iphone to the Linux computer (again, using uxplay). Now I'd like to make it so that when the ipad (which does not have LTE and does not have the tethering option) is plugged into the Linux computer, it will obtain a "local" IP address from my laptop (i.e., not on the work network), and I could launch uxplay using this "mini network" and mirror my ipad.

I have seen a similar setup for the raspberry pi, but don't have enough knowledge to adapt it to my situation: https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2019/11/02/pi4-usb-c-gadget/ In particular, I don't understand what the shell script does...